# php Local host is currently unable to access this request

Tags: javascript, php, html

```html
<?php
$handle = fopen("pictures_list.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
$linea = fgets($handle);
$lineb = fgets($handle);
$linec = fgets($handle);
}
fclose($handle);
else {
echo "can't find file";
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Pictures</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssstyles.css" />
</head>
<body>

<center>
<h1>Bridge Pictures</h1>
<br />
<p class="ex" align="justify">This site or call.</p>
<br/>
<h3> Click on image to zoom in. Place mouse on image for Time Stamp</h3>
<div id="container">
      <ul>
            <li>
                  <a href="<?php echo $linea; ?>">
                  <figure>
                  <img src="<?php echo $linea; ?>" width="400"/>
                  <figcaption> <?php echo $linea; ?> </figcaption>
                  </figure>
                  </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                  <a href="<?php echo $lineb; ?>">
                  <figure>
                  <img src="<?php echo $lineb; ?>" width="400"/>
                  <figcaption><?php echo $lineb; ?></figcaption>
                  </figure>
                  </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                  <a href="<?php echo $linec; ?>">
                  <figure>
                  <img src="<?php echo $linec; ?>" width="400"/>
                  <figcaption> <?php echo $linec; ?> </figcaption>
                  </figure>
                  </a>
            </li>

      </ul>
      <span class="button prevButton"></span>
      <span class="button nextButton"></span>
<br />
<h2><a href=" http://www.xyz/"> Click here for a list of all images </a></h2>
</ul>
</center>
</div>
<script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
            var pages = $('#container li'), current=0;
            var currentPage,nextPage;
            var timeoutID;
            var buttonClicked=0;

            var handler1=function(){
                  buttonClicked=1;
                  $('#container .button').unbind('click');
                  currentPage= pages.eq(current);
                  if($(this).hasClass('prevButton'))
                  {
                        if (current <= 0)
                              current=pages.length-1;
                        else
                              current=current-1;
                        nextPage = pages.eq(current); 

                        nextPage.css("marginLeft",-604);
                        nextPage.show();
                        nextPage.animate({ marginLeft: 0 }, 800,function(){
                              currentPage.hide();
                        });
                        currentPage.animate({ marginLeft: 604 }, 800,function(){
                              $('#container .button').bind('click',handler1);
                        });
                  }
                  else
                  {
 if (current >= pages.length-1)
                              current=0;
                        else
                              current=current+1;
                        nextPage = pages.eq(current); 

                        nextPage.css("marginLeft",604);
                        nextPage.show();
                        nextPage.animate({ marginLeft: 0 }, 800,function(){
                        });
                        currentPage.animate({ marginLeft: -604 }, 800,function(){
                              currentPage.hide();
                              $('#container .button').bind('click',handler1);
                        });
                  }           
            }

            var handler2=function(){
                  if (buttonClicked==0)
                  {
                  $('#container .button').unbind('click');
                  currentPage= pages.eq(current);
                  if (current >= pages.length-1)
                        current=0;
                    else
                        current=current+1;
                  nextPage = pages.eq(current); 
                  nextPage.css("marginLeft",604);
                  nextPage.show();
                  nextPage.animate({ marginLeft: 0 }, 800,function(){
                  });
                  currentPage.animate({ marginLeft: -604 }, 800,function(){
                        currentPage.hide();
                        $('#container .button').bind('click',handler1);
                  });
                  timeoutID=setTimeout(function(){
                        handler2(); 
                  }, 4000);
                  }
            }

            $('#container .button').click(function(){
                  clearTimeout(timeoutID);
                  handler1();
            });

            timeoutID=setTimeout(function(){
                  handler2(); 
                  }, 4000);
            
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My html and javascript seemed to work just fine previously with hardcoded image names. I am now using php to input images from a text file but now it doesn't seem to work. I get that the local host is currently unable to handle this request error.

I tried to write a simple php program such as this and this seems to work just fine. I'm sure I'm missing something very silly but can't seem to figure it out. Please help

```html
<?php
$handle = fopen("pictures_list.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
$linea = fgets($handle);
$lineb = fgets($handle);
$linec = fgets($handle);
fclose($handle);
}

else {
echo "can't find file";
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
      <ul>
            <li>
                  <a href="<?php echo $linea; ?>">
                  <figure>
                  <img src="<?php echo $linea; ?>" width="400"/>
                  <figcaption> <?php echo $linea; ?> </figcaption>
                  </figure>
                  </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                  <a href="<?php echo $lineb; ?>">
                  <figure>
                  <img src="<?php echo $lineb; ?>" width="400"/>
                  <figcaption><?php echo $lineb; ?></figcaption>
                  </figure>
                  </a>
            </li>
      </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you debug by trying to e.g. die($linea); to make sure the image names are still correct?

Comment: When you get a 500 error, you should check the error log on the server for the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't get anything:

```
if (...) {
    ...
}
fclose($handle);   
else {           // syntax error: "unexpected else (T_ELSE)"
```

You cannot have any code "between" the `}` and `else`. They MUST be next to each other:

```
 if (...) {
      ...
 } else { 
    ...
 }
```

Since that's a fatal syntax error, the script dies, and probably causes a 500 error in your server.

Comment: Oh my god, I feel so silly. It works now, thank you @Marc B

Comment: If you didn't get that fatal parse error message, you're probably running with error_reporting and display_errors off. They should NEVER be off on a devel/debug system.